# How to take the backup of SQlite DB and upload it to Google Drive Via Ionic2?

Tags: sqlite, ionic2, google-drive-api

I have an Ionic2 application. All the data stored in SQLite db. When the user signed out from the application, I need to take the back up of sqlite and upload it to Google Drive.

Could anybody help me to crack this?

### Edit

Added cordova plugin to transfer file `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

Upload method

```
upload() {
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: '<file name>',
        headers: {<Authorization headers>}
    }

    fileTransfer.upload('<file path>', '<google drive api>', options)
        .then((data) => {

        }, (err) => {

        })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack you need to show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with YOUR solution.   May i suggest Googleing Sqllie backup and Google drive api